# Error: The getter 'WordPair' isn't defined for the class 'MyApp'. When going through the "Write your first app" guide in the flutter docs

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and going through the "Write your first app" guide in the flutter docs. I get this error, Error: The getter 'WordPair' isn't defined for the class 'MyApp'. When trying to run the app.

I am confused because WordPair is a class, I don't believe it needs a getter. I tried to copy and paste the code straight from the Flutter docs and I get the same error. Could it be a problem with dependencies?

I will attach the code and the `pubspec.yaml` file. Would appreciate a response from anyone. Thank you!
Here is my code:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final wordPair = WordPair.random();
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Text(wordPair.asPascalCase),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Here is the `pubspec.yaml` file

```
    name: startup_namer
    description: First Flutter app. Startup Namer.
    
    # The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
    # pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
    publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
    
    # The following defines the version and build number for your application.
    # A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
    # followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
    # Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
    # build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
    # In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
    # Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
    # In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
    # Read more about iOS versioning at
    # https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
    version: 1.0.0+1
    
    environment:
      sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
    
    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
    
    
      # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
      # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
      cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
      english_words: ^3.1.5
    
    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
      pedantic: ^1.4.0
    
    # For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
    # following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
    
    # The following section is specific to Flutter.
    flutter:
    
      # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
      # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
      # the material Icons class.
      uses-material-design: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be the simple reason: after adding some libraries that not yet compiled in app, hot reload can't work. So You need to stop application and run again (it will run recompile process)

Comment: Wow. Can't believe the solution was so simple. Thank you so much for taking the time to explain the fix.